# Runs a C file through the preprocessor and save the result into another file

Tags: c, shell

Hello please sorry if I am being a bother but I frankly need help on how to write a script that runs a c file which is saved in a variable $FLASH whose output is saved in a file named melody

Comment: `FLASH="$(cpp ...)"` `echo "$FLASH" > melody` ? I don't understand what you need to do really. In any case, it sounds like the wrong solution.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I think he means that `$FLASH` contains the name of the `.c` file.

Comment: @Barmar Ah... yeah, that makes more sense :-)

Comment: `cpp $FLASH -o melody`?